# Mac terminal says "-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe" on opening

Tags: terminal, bash

I opened my terminal, like I do most days Mon-Fri, and was surprised to see this error:

```
Last login: Fri Jul 27 17:19:25 on console
-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe
SomeMac:~ user568458$
```

Everything seems to work fine currently, but things like this worry me because they could be a clue that something is wrong which might blow up later.

Doing some searches suggests that [this message can appear if someone introduces an error into `.bash_profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802707/terminal-broken-bash-echo-write-error-broken-pipe) - but I haven't modified that file in a long time and haven't installed anything that would modify it recently. In fact, my `.bash_profile` file reports its "Modified" date as February (5 months ago).

How can I investigate what caused this or how serious it is? Or is it something that can be safely ignored?

---

In case it's relevant, since that other linked Q&A mentions `.bash_profile` commands related to `NVM` (which I do use), here's the contents of my `.bash_profile` file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

But this doesn't include the infinite-loop causing line `source ~/.bash_profile` in [that other guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803136/568458), and these have (as far as I can) not changed since February, so I'm not sure how they could be the cause of the error.

Comment: You should take a look at .nvm/nvm.sh and .nvm/bash_completion, as both of t hem are loaded by your bash profile. If you can't find anything wrong there, append them to your original question (if they aren't too big) so others can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

A shell's error message is really straight forward. The structure consists of the command, the filename, and the error message.

```
command: filename: message
```

Your error message is a bit more complicated in the fact that you are using  a shell builtin command and the filename is a stream through a pipe. So, my best guess would be that somewhere in `nvm.sh`, there is a line that is something like `echo something | command`, where `command` is closing the pipe before `echo` finishes sending the data.